# Weight change but clothes still fit

Tags: weight-gain

I'm 15 5'9.5 and weigh 151lb I recently used to weigh 145 but my clothes still fit and my waist is still 32.5 inches and it had been a few months since I've weight lifted I just started back so I don't see how it's muscle gain cause I gained 6lb in a week

Comment: Most likely water retention. Weight fluctuates quite a bit even during the course of a day.

Comment: 6 lbs is too little for clothes to be affected. But yeah, it's possibly a combination of water weight and fat.

Comment: Even if it's not water weight, there are a lot of places weight can go on the body. I've gained 5 pounds and had no change in waist, biceps, thighs, calves, chest, neck, or hips. Bigger traps don't make your clothes too tight.

Comment: Can we assume that you didn't wear different clothing/shoes on the times you were weighed and it was on the same scale? 6 pounds is within a fair range of error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. You were just low on water content.
2. You have put on muscle mass.

Possibility 1 is the most probable cause.
Your body loses water and your weight fluctuates in a matter of hours.
So, if you are dehydrated, then probably you lost a few pounds.

Possibility 2:
You could have put on 2.7kg (6lbs) of muscle mass in a week, but only if you had worked out hardcore and took a lot of nutrition.

I weighed 85kg before and now I weigh 106kg and my clothes still fit. Don't take your clothes as a parameter to measure your gain/loss.

Comment: You cannot gain 21 kg *(over 40 lbs),* and for it not to be reflected on your clothing. You're either lying or someone's playing a joke on you.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD Or he has a skater wardrobe. ;)

Comment: HOORAY FOR MUSCLE MASS!